# How to choose a random interaction with user input in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, random

I want to be able to randomly choose a joke from a list of jokes, and continue on through the joke (whether it be knock knock, or whatever else) with user input.

I know what I need to do to have one simple knock knock joke with user interaction, but I want to be able to do several different ones at random.

So in terms of pseudocode, I'd like it to look something like this:

```
print("Would you like to hear a joke?")
answer = input()
if answer == ("Yes"):
   choose joke from list of jokes ["joke a", "joke b", "joke c"]
   print("randomly chosen joke")
   continue on with user input
else:
   sys.exit()
```

Comment: So, is your question: how to choose an item from a list randomly?

Comment: `random.choice`  - did you search at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Randomly selecting an element from a list can be done like this

```
import random
joke_list = ['joke1', 'joke2', 'joke3']
random.choice(joke_list)
```

But as it is, this just selects a string. What you want is something that chooses an *interaction*. That can be done with something like this

```
def joke1():
    #Execute joke 1
    pass

def joke2():
    #Execute joke 1
    pass

joke_list = [joke1, joke2] #list of functions
import random
joke = random.choice(joke_list)
joke() #execute the selected joke, which is a function
```

So to summarize: make your jokes functions instead of strings so they can each be a unique interaction, make a list of functions, select an random element with `random.choice`

Comment: ahh, you posted that while I was typing up an answer to do the same thing!

Comment: I did this, but I get an error that says 'str' object is not callable.

Answer (score 1):

```
joke = random.choice(["joke a", "joke b", "joke c"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers and comments have suggested using `random.choice`, but I think that's actually the wrong thing to use in this case, since it may repeat the same joke more than once within the same session. I suspect that would be a lousy experience for the user, so here's an alternative.

Use `random.shuffle` to randomly order a list, then iterate over it to get your jokes one by one until you either run out or the user doesn't want any more:

```
import random

jokes = [x, y, z]     # these could be strings, or functions as suggested by GraphicsNoob

random.shuffle(jokes) # put the list in a random order

it = iter(jokes)      # an iterator over the shuffled list

first = next(it)
print(first)          # tell the first joke, could be first() instead

for joke in it:       # loop over the rest of the jokes
    response = input("Would you like to here another joke?"):   # ask about more
    if response.lower().startswith("n"):                   # stop if the user says "no"
        break
    print(joke)       # tell the next joke, could be joke() if you're using functions
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it:

```
import random

x = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
print x[random.randint(0, len(x)-1)]
```

Generate a random integer between 0 and however long your joke array is; print that array element.

Comment: Even if we wanted to use this instead of `random.choice` for some reason, it wouldn't work: `randint` includes the upper bound, and so sometimes you'd get IndexErrors.